# HDMI No Sound - X1200/Toshiba TV/Windows XP

Tags: audio, hdmi

The video card is ATI x1200.  The OS is Windows XP.
This setup has worked fairly well for the previous LCD (a LG 32inch).

My mom bought a 32inch LCD, Toshiba 32DT2U1 a couple of days ago.
With the same setup, the display is fine, but there is no sound coming out.
The Audio tab is greyed out...

I tried:
Update ATI Catalyst driver
Update Windows XP
Disable Realtek on board audio...

still nothing...

:-(

Comment: Is the TV set to get it sound source from HDMI? Which "Audio tab" are you speaking of? Have you seen: http://superuser.com/questions/115785/windows-7-does-not-recognize-hdmi-audio-output?

Comment: Good point on the TV config. I should look up the manual.  Audio Tab I am referring to , is the first tab when you open "Sound and Audio Device" from Control Panel.