# No audio through display port after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, hdmi

I recently bought a new SSD for my laptop (HP ProBook 6450b with Intel HD Graphics and an i3 processor) and decided to install Windows 8 on it, I used Windows 7 on my previous drive. I've run the latest Windows and driver updates.

Now the laptop no longer recognizes my TV (connected through DP -> HDMI) as an audio playback device. This means that the sound goes through the internal speakers. This was never a problem with Windows 7.

[image]

Note that the laptop does not have any HDMI ports.

I have been searching through forums for hours to no avail.

Comment: Did you go to HP's site and get all the drivers for Windows 8 directly from them?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I went to intel and downloaded the graphics drivers from them. Didn't think to try HP's site, testing now.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There were no drivers for Windows 8 but I installed the graphics and audio drivers for Windows 7 from HP's site. This did not fix the issue :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 does not recognize HDMI audio output](http://superuser.com/questions/115785/windows-7-does-not-recognize-hdmi-audio-output)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Nvidia seems to have had a similar issue a few years ago as I have discovered when searching for a solution. However, there's nothing from Nvidia in my PC. I'd argue that this is not a duplicate. My laptop does recognize HDMI and it did work on Windows 7. Either way, the two answers provided in that thread does not solve my issue.